# Php shell_exec utf-8 encoding

Tags: php, powershell, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem calling PowerShell script using `shell_exec` containing utf-8 characters. I have a working PHP script that writes a (.ps1) file containing the script text and then executes it like so:

```
$result=shell_exec('powershell.exe -command C:\Apache24\htdocs\Test.ps1');
```

The script works just fine if it only contains English characters, however - Czech letters with accents are displayed incorrectly when executing the script, which leads to errors.

I know that both PHP and PowerShell accept utf-8 characters, so it must be the command prompt that causes the problem. `Shell_exec` relies on CMD to launch the PowerShell and execute the script. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you set your locale to `cs_CZ.UTF-8` prior to `shell_exec`?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What should be the code?

Comment: `$locale = 'cs_CZ.UTF-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @BenH, yet it did not solve the issue.